# How to count Exec Stored Procedure output values count based on conditions?

Tags: sql-server

I Have one stored Procedure name called "sp_Proc_EmployeeDetails"

In this Procedure return values like below format:

```
SNo   EmpName  EmpNumber
----------------------------
1       abc      101
2       abc      102
3       abc1     103
4       abc2     104
5       abc2     105
6       abc2     106
```

In this above result I need below output while executing the stored procedure.

```
E.g:
Exec sp_Proc_EmployeeDetails

 Output:
 -------------
 abc Count  = 2
 abc1 Count  = 1
 abc2 Count = 3
```

Comment: Somebody is going to suggest you use `INSERT ... EXEC`, then query over the result. My suggestion is to look at the logic of `sp_proc_employeedetails` to see if it uses queries that can easily be adapted to use `SELECT EmpName, Count(*) FROM ... GROUP BY EmpName` directly, as it won't break if the stored procedure's output format changes and may perform better.

Comment: What is this stored procedure doing? you may want a view instead.

Comment: Off-topic; there are good arguments against prefixing your [procedures](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25348/still-wrong-to-start-the-name-of-a-user-stored-procedure-with-sp) sp_.

Comment: do not start your procedure names with sp_ read this http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: why do this in a stored procedure ? It sounds like just another query. If you really want the query inside your DB than use a view. This is typical job for a view not for a procedure

Comment: sure. Thanks for your infomation

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table Emp (
SNo  int ,
EmpName varchar(50),
EmpNumber  int
) 
go

insert into  Emp 
select 1       ,'abc'     , 101
union all select  2       ,'abc'      ,102
union all select  3       ,'abc1'     ,103
union all select  4       ,'abc2'     ,104
union all select  5       ,'abc2'     ,105
union all select  6       ,'abc2'     ,106
go

create proc sp_Proc_EmployeeDetails
as 
begin
    select EmpName + ' Count = ' + cast( COUNT(*) as varchar(10)) as  [Output:] from  Emp 
group by EmpName
end 
go

exec sp_Proc_EmployeeDetails

Output:
--------------------- 
abc Count = 2
abc1 Count = 1
abc2 Count = 3
```